# Static file not working in Django "js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" 404

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

All static file is probably working but 2 files are not working. I want results like this in my HTML file.
**my code**

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/asyncloader.min.js' %}"></script>
   <!-- JS bootstrap -->
   <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
   <!-- popper-js -->
   <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/swiper-bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
   <!-- Iscotop -->
   <script src="{% static 'js/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>

   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/slick.min.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/streamlab-core.js' %}"></script>  
   <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
```

**Cmd Error**

```
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 55322
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 160392
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 154139
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/fontawesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/js/swiper-bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 140317
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/ionicons.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:56] "GET /static/css/owl.carousel.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/images/background/asset-6.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 315755
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/images/background/asset-5.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 248498
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/images/background/asset-4.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 340003
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/images/background/asset-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 179687
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/css/flaticon/fonts/ionicons.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 188508
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /static/images/background/asset-3.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 2050462
Not Found: /images/background/asset-4.jpeg
Not Found: /images/background/asset-1.jpeg
Not Found: /images/background/asset-3.jpeg
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /images/background/asset-4.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 2454
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /images/background/asset-3.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 2454
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /images/background/asset-1.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 2454
Not Found: /js/owl.carousel.min.js
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /js/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 2438
Not Found: /js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
[17/Apr/2022 02:54:57] "GET /js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 2465
```

**I want result like**
[my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmwVW.jpg)

**But I get**

[django templates use static file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WsXR.jpg)

Comment: Please post code, not images.  Here's [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10951070).  You should include your full index.html for starters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think now you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

just go to `streamlab-core.js` and disable call top a function `registerDependencies()` to disable versioning

Note: don't forget to remove `asyncloader` to each dependencies function call like  `owl_carousel();` or else they will not work

Answer (score 0):

{% load static %}
{% static 'images/background/asset-4.jpeg' %}